# RSpec - failing test unless local variable is called from pry point

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have the following code:

```
## teams_controller.rb

def destroy
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    team_admins = team.team_admins
    binding.pry
    team.destroy!
    team_admins.each(&:update_team_admin_role_if_needed!)
  end

  respond_with_200(team, serializer: V1::User::Management::TeamSerializer)
end
```

And the corresponding spec to ensure the last line of the above code fires:

```
## teams_controller_spec.rb

it 'demotes team admins to employees when needed' do
  team_admin_account = create(:account)
  admin_team_membership = create(:team_membership, team: @team, admin: true, account: team_admin_account)
  team_admin_account.update!(role: Role.team_admin)

  expect { process_destroy(team_id: @team.slug) }
    .to change { team_admin_account.reload.role }
    .from(Role.team_admin)
    .to(Role.employee)
end
```

When I use the above code in my application it works as expected, however the spec fails as the account apparently never has their role updated:

```
 expected `team_admin_account.reload.role` to have changed from #<Role id: 4, add_to_first_user_in_organisation: false, title: "Team admin", created_at: "2020-01-03 09:04:28", updated_at: "2020-01-03 09:04:28", management: false, cms_access: false> to #<Role id: 3, add_to_first_user_in_organisation: false, title: "Employee", created_at: "2020-01-03 09:04:28", updated_at: "2020-01-03 09:04:28", management: false, cms_access: false>, but did not change
```

When I hit the pry point in my spec and quit out straight away, the spec fails. Likewise when there is no pry point.

However when I enter `team_admins` at the pry point (which returns the one team_admin I create in my spec) and then quit out of the spec, the spec passes and the account has their role updated.

Anyone have any idea why manually calling `team_admins` makes my spec pass?

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

The following change to the code also makes the spec pass:

```
def destroy
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    team_admins = team.team_admins
    puts team_admins                        ## <---- Adding this makes the spec pass
    team.destroy!
    team_admins.each(&:update_team_admin_role_if_needed!)
  end

  respond_with_200(team, serializer: V1::User::Management::TeamSerializer)
end
```

Comment: When you say "quit out of the spec" what do you mean? Do you mean existing `pry`?

Comment: That's right - ctrl + d to exit the pry point and continue the spec's execution

Comment: `team_admins.inspect` returns the one team admin I create in the spec, and manually calling that from within the pry point also makes the spec pass

Comment: Very weird... How is `team.team_admins` defined? Perhaps somehow the act of printing them to the console "actualises" the list, whereas maintaining it as a `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy` means it's only truly evaluated later -- so by the time your code hits `team_admins.each`, it's being treated as an empty array?

Comment: What is `team_admins`? What class? I suspect it's something lazy which does not fully execute until used and resolved into an Array.

Comment: Hmm you may be onto something... it's an ActiveRecord::AsociationRelation with one object inside

Comment: Maybe you could force the behaviour by using `team_admins = team.team_admins.to_a`? Or maybe you could update the team roles **before** running `team.destroy!`? You haven't shown how `update_team_admin_role_if_needed!` is defined, so I can't say if that's possible.

Comment: I can confirm that changing it to `team_admins = team.team_admins.to_a` makes the spec pass with no further code needed

Comment: Many thanks for the help... I'm still not sure why the active record relation doesn't persist throughout the spec though.. it seems to get evaluated and then forgotten about?

Comment: Think I'm understanding it now - thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`team_admins` is an AssociationRelation from `team`. This does not execute a query until referenced, such as with `each` or `puts`.

`team.destroy!` is called before `team_admins.each` is called. So when `team_admins.each` executes there is no more `team` and thus no `team_admins`. You should be able to verify this by watching `logs/test.log` and looking at the queries and when they are executed.

Congratulations, you've found a bug. Execute `team_admins.each` before destroying `team`.

Comment: Doesn't my first line of code in the destroy action, `team_admins = team.team_admins`, mean the variable should be stored even if I delete the team?

Comment: Or you're saying this doesn't actually execute until we do something with the `team_admins` local variable?

Comment: Yes. Associations and other queries can delay execution until needed to avoid unnecessary queries. You should be able to check if the TeamAdmins are loaded with [`team_admins.loaded?`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html#method-i-loaded-3F).

Comment: *The variable* is an unreferenced query. Rails tries to run queries "just in time". For example, that's why it's possible to write: `x = User.all; x = x.where(name: 'Tom'); x = x.where(location: 'StackOverflow'); puts x.count` -- and this only executes one query, not 4.

Comment: `team_admins.loaded?
=> nil
`

Comment: And thanks for the explanation - it's making sense to me now :)